# dylib destructor does not get called

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, code-injection, dylib

I have a dylib which I can load via injection on mac os x.
Constructor call works well.

```
 __attribute__((constructor))
 static void initialize()
```

But destructor does not get called? Thus resources initialized leaks.

```
__attribute__((destructor))
static void destroy()
```

1. Does dylib gets unloaded automatically if application quits?
2. Does injected dylib gets unloaded automatically if application quits?
3. How can we unload dylib from the application at runtime? As its injection code I can access private area. Is there a command to do this?

Comment: Question Continued http://stackoverflow.com/q/7553355/802921

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1, 2: No. Libraries aren't really unloaded when an application exits -- they just happen to disappear along with the rest of the process, in the same way that other resources (e.g, file handles, mapped memory, sockets, *etc*) are released on exit.

3: Depends on how you injected the library. If you loaded it using something like `dlopen()`, you should be able to unload the library using `dlclose()`, for instance; `NSBundle` has something equivalent.

Keep in mind that unloading libraries is messy. In particular, it's unsafe to unload a library which contains any ObjC classes, as the runtime may have cached references to your classes.