# Monitor start and close of process?

Tags: macos, cocoa, process, macos-carbon, dylib

Is there a way to monitor processes in the Mac OS X before they Start & End?

I have a dynamic which I would like to inject in few selected processes before the start, so that hooking can be performed. And would like to do the reverse when application quits, i.e. when application quits I want to unload that library from those process & thus perform unhooking.

What can be the best solution for my situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When application quits it unload's that library from those process automatically. I had a bug which prevented calling of destructor from dylib.

Answer (score 1):

In Carbon, you can register for the `kEventClassApplication/kEventAppLaunched` event. For quitting, I think looking for an event might not be the best approach; you may not be able to respond in time before the process actually ends. It may be better to have your injected code install an `atexit` handler or something.